# Как уменьшить задержку (пинг) с конекретным сайтом?

Tags: ping

Мне очень надо, что бы у меня с определенным сайтом было идеальное соединение.Что бы пинг был меньше 20.Что я могу сделать,что бы этого добиться?
Дело не в скорости интернета тк с другими сайтами и прочим проблем нет.Скорость 100 мб/c.Как можно максимально улучшить отклик/соединение с сайтом?
Если что сайт в домене .ru? Спасибо!
ps пинг сейчас в районе 40-50.

Comment: Вашими силами ничего нельзя сделать. Проверьте трассировку маршрута до сайта, посмотрите на задержки, и обратитесь в тех поддержку вашего провайдера

Comment: Задержки возникают на оборудовании, которым Вы не управляете.Так что и сделать Вы ничего не сможете. Более того, 80% за то, что и провайдер Ваш ближний тут не при чём (впрочем, трассировка с TCP-пингом поможет выявить, на каком именно узле возникает задержка).